# Nested GROUP_CONCAT MySQL?

Tags: mysql

[image: Database Layout]

Ok, say I have a database layout similar to the one in the example I have provided. In the above examples movies have releases in languages and those movie_releases also have theatre releases in different theatres.

Now if I wanted to query the database to get all of a movie's theatre releases as well as all movie_releases, how would I do that?

The current code I have is:

```
select
      GROUP_CONCAT(movie.name, ",", language.lang, ",", GROUP_CONCAT(theatre.name)) as releases
from
    movie
        left join movie_releases on movie_releases.movie_id = movie.id
        left join language on movie_release.language_id = language.id
        left join theatre_release on theatre_release.movie_release_id = movie_release.id
        left join theatre on theatre.id = theatre_release.theatre_id
```

Obviously this doesn't work because you can't nest GROUP_CONCAT functions like this.

My desired output would be something like

```
["Spiderman", "English", ["Cinema Theatre", "Garden Cinemas"]]
["Spiderman", "Spanish", ["El Cine Grande"]]
["Batman", "English", ["Town Movies"]]
```

Comment: A result set without a dataset is like a stick without a lollipop. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for not being helpful at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        '["', `movie`.`name`, '"',
        ', ',
        '"', releases.lang, '"',
        ', [',
        releases.theatres,
        ']]'
    ) AS `release`
FROM
    movie
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        movie_id,
        `language`.lang,
        GROUP_CONCAT('"', theatre.`name`, '"') AS theatres
    FROM
        movie_release
    LEFT JOIN theatre_release ON theatre_release.movie_release_id = movie_release.id
    LEFT JOIN theatre ON theatre.id = theatre_release.theatre_id
    LEFT JOIN `language` ON `language`.id = movie_release.language_id
    GROUP BY
        movie_id,
        language_id
) AS releases ON releases.movie_id = movie.id
```

You can group the theatres in a subselect and then join them onto the movies by their relation over the releases.

By bringing the data in your format it might make the query a little harder to read. So here is the query without the fancy formatting.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        `movie`.`name`,
        ' ',
        releases.lang,
        ' ',
        releases.theatres
    ) AS `release`
FROM
    movie
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        movie_id,
        `language`.lang,
        GROUP_CONCAT(theatre.`name`) AS theatres
    FROM
        movie_release
    LEFT JOIN theatre_release ON theatre_release.movie_release_id = movie_release.id
    LEFT JOIN theatre ON theatre.id = theatre_release.theatre_id
    LEFT JOIN `language` ON `language`.id = movie_release.language_id
    GROUP BY
        movie_id,
        language_id
) AS releases ON releases.movie_id = movie.id
```

To add the delimiteres you only have to adjust the `CONCAT` or the `GROUP_CONCAT`